# Bootstrap - center inner div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this : http://www.bootply.com/apUgehnGLq

Why width of red box is so big ? I want it to finish immediately after last box, which is a box with tag CCC and then center the whole red box.

Answer (score 0):

The border adds pixels to the width of the box, so the last box goes on a new line. You can set `box-sizing: border-box;` on the `body` and a padding on the `.border` instead of a margin to achieve what you want.

I updated your code: http://www.bootply.com/1s5ESfKlod

Read more about what the `box-sizing` property can do at [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).

*Update*

See code here: http://www.bootply.com/ASWCuTHrZy

You can control the items in this example using `flex-basis`, where the X items is **3**.

```
  flex-basis: calc(100% * 1/3);
```

So 100 divided by 1/3 makes 33.333..%, that's the width of the AAA, BBB, CCC containers. DDD will go to the next line.

*All used CSS:*

```
body * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.border {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid black;
  }


#inner {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 80%;
}

.container-fluid { 
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-content: flex-start;
  }

.border {
  flex-basis: calc(100% * 1/3);
}
```

Comment: it's not what I wanted. I want those inner boxes to be separated and if there is more than N ( dependes on the screen size) then others should go to the next line.

Comment: it should break line after CCC, but all those boxes should be moved to the right

Answer (score 0):

Since you're working with % in the inner div you are going to have to make the percentages bigger and the div smaller till you have the size you prefer, like so: 
http://www.bootply.com/juFV1xgpNY

Just play around with the withs of the .inner and the divs inside of it.

Comment: If no one understands what you want maybe you should ask your question more clearly. Also show us what you've tried, because as far as I read your question what i did did exactly what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The issues you are having with the 4 columns not lining up is due to the margin you have set in the .border class, as well as the class for #inner id. So, if you remove the border margin we should be able to resolve all the issues. Like so:

```
<div id="center" class="col-lg-7">
  <div class="col-md-4 border">AAA</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 border">BBB</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 border">CCC</div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="col-md-12 border">DDD</div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, if you would like to have all the 4 columns to line up, you can just code it like so:

```
<div id="center" class="col-lg-7">
  <div class="col-md-3 border">AAA</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 border">BBB</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 border">CCC</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 border">DDD</div>
</div>
```

You can view the sample code here: http://www.bootply.com/GZJwteX6yT

I hope this helps you!